# create dynamic html elements and add to table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, spark-view-engine

I used to some thing like this in jsp.

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ page errorPage="/showError.jsp" %>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
%>
<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/production">
    select id,location,zone,ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(date_recp,'%m/%d/%Y'),'00-00-0000') as date_recp,qry_id ,cust_name,qry_recvd,qry_mode,ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%m/%d/%Y'),'00-00-0000') as start_date,
        timing,qry_type,qry_cat,qry_det,ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(date_esclation,'%m/%d/%Y'),'00-00-0000') as date_esclation,ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(date_recp_ho,'%m/%d/%Y'),'00-00-0000') as date_recp_ho,
        ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(date_recp_ho,'%m/%d/%Y'),'00-00-0000') as final_date,remarks,qry_stat from cust_supp where final_date is null or final_date='0000-00-00'
</sql:query>
<html>     
<head>
    <title>Customer Support Search Operation</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= path %>/js/style.css" />
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "<%= path%>/css/demo_table.css";
            @import "<%= path%>/css/demo_table_jui.css";
            @import "<%= path%>/css/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css";
            @import "<%= path%>/css/TableTools.css";
            @import "<%= path%>/css/TableTools_JUI.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= path%>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= path %>/js/tcal.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= path %>/css/tcal.css" />

<script src="<%= path%>/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= path%>/js/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= path%>/js/TableTools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="<%=path%>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%=path%>/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%=path%>/js/tinybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= path%>/js/send_data.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="brand" style="background:url('<%=path%>/images/head.jpg') no-repeat ;"></div>
<body>
    <div class="forms">
<form style="height:450pt;width:95%;margin-left:5pt;margin-top:0" name ="form" action="<%=path%>/Download">    
<input type="hidden" name="query" value="q0" />
<input type="hidden" name="dwld" value="cust_supp" />

<table width="95%" id="dataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
<tr>
    <th width="20pt"><b>S.no</b></th>
 <th><b>Query ID</b></th>
<th><b>Zone</b></th>
<th><b>Location</b></th>
<th><b>Customer Name</b></th>
<th><b>Query Received</b></th>
<th><b>Date of Receipt</b></th>
<th><b>Mode of Query</b></th>
<th><b>Start Fall-Up Date</b></th>
<th><b>Timing</b></th>
<th><b>Query Type</b></th>
<th><b>Query Category</b></th>
<th><b>Query Details</b></th>
<th><b>Date of Escalation</b></th>
<th><b>Date of Receipt HO/Client/Bank</b></th>
<th><b>Final Date</b></th>
<th><b>Remarks</b></th>
<th><b>Query Status</b></th>
<th><b>Update</b></th>
</tr>
    </thead><tbody>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
<tr>
<td>${row.id}</td>
<td><span>${row.qry_id}</span></td>
<td><span>${row.zone}</span></td>
<td><span>${row.location}</span></td>
<td><span class="editable">${row.cust_name}</span></td>
<td><select name="query_rcvd" >
        <option value="${row.qry_recvd}" selected>${row.qry_recvd}</option>
          <option value="Client">Client</option>
          <option value="HO">HO</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="${row.date_recp}" /></td>
<td><select name="mode" >
        <option value="${row.qry_mode}" selected>${row.qry_mode}</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
        <option value="E-mail">E-mail</option>
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="${row.start_date}"/></td>
<td><span class="editable">${row.timing}</span></td>
<td><select name="nature">
        <option value="${row.qry_type}" selected>${row.qry_type}</option>
         <option value="ECS Debit">ECS Debit</option>
          <option value="ECS Credit">ECS Credit</option>
          <option value="ASP">ASP</option>
           <option value="MF">MF</option>
          <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
</select></td>
<td><select name="category">
        <option value="${row.qry_cat}" selected>${row.qry_cat}</option>
        <option value="Status of the Transaction" >Status of the Transaction</option>
        <option value="Mandate Related Queries">Mandate Related Queries</option>
        <option value="Mandate Re-submission Cases">Mandate Re-submission Cases</option>
        <option value="Wrong Reason Code Given By The Bankers">Wrong Reason Code Given By The Bankers</option>
        <option value="Txn bounced at our end but cust bank a/c debited">Txn bounced at our end but cust bank a/c debited</option>
        <option value="Extra debit in the bank account">Extra debit in the bank account</option>
        <option value="Credit Query">Credit Query</option>
        <option value="R7">R7 Report</option>
</select></td>
<td><span class="editable">${row.qry_det}</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="${row.date_esclation}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="${row.date_recp_ho}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="${row.final_date}"/></td>
<td><span class="editable">${row.remarks}</span></td>
<td><span class="editable">${row.qry_stat}</span></td>
<td><input type="button" class="tab_buttons" value="Update"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That creates a page from `MySql DB` which contains select and input elements within a `html` table, Now I want to achieve the same in an `aspx page`. I tried to add `dynamically` from code behind, but that's completely mixing `c# with html`, I don't want that, As I am new, someone suggested me spark, they said it worked like `jstl` which I used above, I tried but spark is not getting into my head, a simple simple simple example plsss. Or any other better way to achieve that. `MVC` not involved in this so that I can use razor.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure why you say you are "mixing c# with HTML in codebehind."   You can do all the coding in a separate page-derived class file.  Are you using visual studio?  See example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935729/populate-a-table-on-an-asp-net-page

Comment: Thankyou that link helped me, using the repeater.