# Can you use a classic asp table in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am unsure if you can still use a table in asp.net and have the fields filled in via a dataset.
This was done in the old asp.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="Table1">
      <tr> 
        <td class="test1"><strong>Person Number:</strong></td>
        <td class="test2"><%=DataSetvalue("PNum")%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes! you can do it. 
Have a look on following links

```
http://www.shiningstar.net/blog/tables.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_table.asp
```

Comment: Sure, but can you populate it with <%=DataSetvalue("PNum")%> or do you need to write some code to do it?

Comment: Thanks - I mean you don't have to do what is being said here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935729/populate-a-table-on-an-asp-net-page