# How to populate HTML table with SPQuery result

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I've just started playing with developing in SP2010, so I'm complete begginer .
 I've created simple console application with code like this :

```
using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("http://win-e9840laitme"))
{
    using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList myList = currentWeb.Lists["List1"];

        string currentUserName = currentWeb.CurrentUser.Name;

        SPQuery queryInformationAboutCurrentUser = new SPQuery();
        queryInformationAboutCurrentUser.Query = "<Where>" +
                                                  "<Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeName'/><Value Type='Text'>" + currentUserName + "</Value></Eq>" +
                                                  "</Where>";

        List<EmployeeInfo> listEmployeeInfo = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
        SPListItemCollection collectionEmployee = myList.GetItems(queryInformationAboutCurrentUser);

        foreach (SPListItem info in collectionEmployee)
        {
            EmployeeInfo eInfo = new EmployeeInfo();
            eInfo.Deparment = info["Office"].ToString();
            listEmployeeInfo.Add(eInfo);

        }
        foreach (EmployeeInfo eI in listEmployeeInfo)
        {
            SPQuery querySameOffice = new SPQuery();
            querySameOffice.Query = "<Where>" +                                                           
                                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Office'/><Value Type='Choice'>" + eI.Deparment + "</Value></Eq>" +                                                           
                                    "</Where>";
            SPListItemCollection collectionEmployeeDisplay = myList.GetItems(querySameOffice);
            foreach (SPListItem item in collectionEmployeeDisplay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item["EmployeeName"].ToString() + " " + item["PhoneNumber"].ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use that code  inside sharepoint project , and instead of putting result of SPQuery on Console , I want to populate HTML table with the result staticly(without JS or Jquery , if it is possible).
I've created sp project and added ApplicationPage.
My idea was to use `StringBuilder` and something like this :

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();


html.Append("<table border = '1'>");
//Building the Header row.
html.Append("<tr>");            
html.Append("<th>");
html.Append("EmployeeName");
html.Append("</th>");
html.Append("<th>");
html.Append("PhoneNumber");
html.Append("</th>");
html.Append("</tr>");
```

and in the last foreach loop this code :

```
foreach (SPListItem item in collectionEmployeeDisplay)
{
    html.Append("<tr>");
    html.Append("<td>");
    html.Append(item["EmployeeName"].ToString());
    html.Append("</td>");

    html.Append("<td>");
    html.Append(item["PhoneBook"].ToString());
    html.Append("</td>");

    html.Append("</tr>");
}

//Table end.
html.Append("</table>");
//Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

I beleive there are more elegant solutions to this problem, and if you now it please give me idea .Thank you.

Comment: you're missing a closing `}` btw.. I will fix your formatting

Comment: `foreach (SPListItem item in collectionEmployeeDisplay)` what's with all the extra `{  }` please fix this mess.. and post readable code..

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935729/populate-a-table-on-an-asp-net-page

Comment: thank you MethodMan, I'll check that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.First we need to add `Repeater` into `PlaceHolderMain` :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEmployees" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1" style="width:70%">
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Name</td>
                <td>Phone Number</td>
                <td>Position</td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("EmployeeName") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("PhoneNumber") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Position") %></td>
        </tr>            
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>


</asp:Repeater>
```

than create another class and add this code into final loop:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in collectionEmployeeDisplay)
                    {
                        DisplayEmployee dE = new DisplayEmployee();
                        dE.EmployeeName = item[Sol.PB1.Fields.EmployeeName].ToString();
                        dE.PhoneNumber = item[Sol.PB1.Fields.PhoneNumber].ToString();
                        dE.Position = item[Sol.PB1.Fields.Position].ToString();
                        display.Add(dE);
                    }

                    rptEmployees.DataSource = display;
                    rptEmployees.DataBind();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use XSLT transformation to convert your SPQuery results to an HTML table. see example of [Applying an XSLT Transform to a DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fd7xytc(v=vs.110).aspx)